# How to download all available artifacts from a specific repository url in build.gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, artifactory

I'm working on a multi-module build which is needed to create an artifact from all WSDLs available on an internal repository. But they are a lot and I don't want to make a list of it, because it might be possible that later another WSDL project is created and needs to be included in the list, if that doesn't happen then the final artifact will be incomplete.

So I need to know if there's any way I can tell gradle to fetch artifacts present on a certain path like `domain.com/path/to/repo/wsdls/` and fetch all available artifacts from this path.

I was thinking of creating a `configuration` which then has this specific repository to download from but it seems configuration does not include a repository and will use defined in `build.gradle`.

Any way to define a download-everything-pattern in dependencies block?

EDIT: Note: WSDL project means soap services in a zip archive

Comment: Does it have to be inside the Gradle script? You can use the JFrog CLI to download a directory from Artifactory.

Comment: Hmm, yeah I need this to build dependencies of project, so yeah.

I found another way, to use JFrog REST API with AQL.

You have any experience with that?

Comment: Yes. Disclaimer - I'm a software developer at JFrog. I would recommend you to prefer JFrog CLI over the REST API. The CLI is much faster and easier to use.

Comment: That's great. Would mean to introduce a dependency I suppose?